# Facebook SDK android

Tags: facebook-android-sdk

I am trying to integrate Facebook sdk into my app.

When I press facebook login button, it shows generic erro "An error occurred. Please try again later"
Anyone knows what might be the cause of it.

```
private final class ButtonOnClickListener implements OnClickListener {

public void onClick(View arg0) {
    if (mFb.isSessionValid()) {
        SessionEvents.onLogoutBegin();
        AsyncFacebookRunner asyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(mFb);
        asyncRunner.logout(getContext(), new LogoutRequestListener());
    } else {
        mFb.authorize(mActivity, mPermissions, new LoginDialogListener());
    }
}
```

}

Can anyone help me with this issue?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you use your app id while running the application.

Answer (score -1):

Try EasyFacebookAndroidSDK,  it's easy to implement. here is a good sample http://kodefun.junian.net/2011/10/easy-facebook-android-sdk-simple.html

Comment: Care to elaborate on this? Your link may be useful, but I can't see how it answers the question that was asked.